# Turning a list into a string or a word

Tags: python, string, list

I know in python there is a way to turn a word or string into a list using `list()`, but is there a way of turning it back, I have:

```
phrase_list = list(phrase)
```

I have tried to change it back into a string using `repr()` but it keeps the syntax and only changes the data type.

I am wondering if there is a way to turn a list, e.g. `['H','e','l','l','o']` into: `'Hello'`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join); call it on a *joining string* and pass in your list:

```
''.join(phrase)
```

Here I used the empty string to join the elements of `phrase`, effectively concatenating all the characters back together into one string.

Demo:

```
>>> phrase = ['H','e','l','l','o']
>>> ''.join(phrase)
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ''.join() is the best approach but you could also you a for loop. (Martijn beat me to it!)

```
hello = ['H','e','l','l','o']

hello2 = ''
for character in hello:
    hello2 += character
```

Comment: Please, his name is *Martijn* and not Martijin :(

Comment: You _could_ do this, but it's very inefficient if the list is long, since it has to allocate memory for a new copy of the `hello2` string (and copy its current contents) each time around the loop.